# How to define a ListView model depending on the value from parent ListView model

Tags: python, windows, listview, qml

I create an application for vehicles' electronic control unit (ECU) diagnostic and now I'm trying to make a module to read errors in ECU using Python and QML.
I've constructed a module using two ListView elements: first ListView is displaying visual containers containing ECU name and a child ListView, which in turn displays a list of errors for this ECU:

[image]

The problem is that I cannot make each child ListView to use its own separate list-model with its own specific errors depending of ECU name from parent ListView. Now I've managed to define only one common list of errors as model, that's why all child ListViews contain same information. How can I define a specific list-model for each child ListView depending on ECU name from a delegate (or model data for this delegate) of parent ListView?

Python code with list-models:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, pyqtProperty

class DTCReading(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        # these lists will change depending on the response of ECU, now for ease of debugging they are defined statically
        self.ecu_list = ['uBCM', 'ACU', 'ESCL']
        self.dtc_list_uBCM = ['p1230', 'u1100', 'f1441']
        self.dtc_list_ACU = ['a1111', 'b2222', 'c3333']
        self.dtc_list_ESCL = ['a1330', 'u0008', 'p1856']

    # signals
    dtc_list_emmition_signal = pyqtSignal()
    ecu_list_emmition_signal = pyqtSignal()


    # ECU list model for parent ListView
    @pyqtProperty(list, notify=ecu_list_emmition_signal)
    def ecu_list_model(self):
        return self.ecu_list 

    def ecu_list_emmition(self):
        self.ecu_list_emmition_signal.emit()

   
    # DTC list model for child ListView 
    @pyqtProperty(list, notify=dtc_list_emmition_signal)
    def dtc_list_model(self):
        return self.dtc_list_uBCM # this list-model should be different depending on the type of ECU from ECU list model

    @pyqtSlot()
    def dtc_list_emmition(self):
        self.dtc_list_emmition_signal.emit()
```

QML code:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Window


Item {
    id: dtcReadingRootItem

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#2c2c2c"
        border.width: 0
        anchors.fill: parent

        //parent ListView with ECU names and child ListView inside
        ListView {
            id: ecuListView
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 110
            anchors.bottomMargin: 10
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            clip: true
            spacing: 5
            interactive: true
            Component.onCompleted: {dtc_reading_connection.dtc_reading()}

            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: ecuDelegate
                height: dtcListView.model.length * 25 + 30
                color: "#383838"
                border.color: "#fff100"
                border.width: 1
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.rightMargin: 20
                anchors.leftMargin: 0

                Label {
                    id: ecuName
                    width: 150
                    color: "#ffffff"
                    text: model.modelData
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    anchors.topMargin: 5
                    styleColor: "#ffffff"
                    font.pointSize: 10
                    font.family: "Verdana"
                    renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                }
                
                //child ListView with error codes
                ListView {                  
                    id: dtcListView
                    height: model.length * 25
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.topMargin: 25
                    anchors.rightMargin: 20
                    anchors.leftMargin: 20
                    clip: true
                    spacing: 5
                    interactive: true
                    Component.onCompleted: {dtc_reading_connection.dtc_reading()}


                    delegate: Rectangle {
                        id: dtcDelegate
                        height: 20
                        visible: true
                        color: "#fff100"
                        anchors.left: parent.left
                        anchors.right: parent.right
                        anchors.rightMargin: 0
                        anchors.leftMargin: 0
                        width: dtcListView.width-40


                        Label {
                            id: testLabel
                            width: 150
                            color: "#000000"
                            text: model.modelData
                            anchors.left: parent.left
                            anchors.right: parent.right
                            anchors.top: parent.top
                            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                            anchors.rightMargin: 20
                            anchors.leftMargin: 20
                            anchors.bottomMargin: 20
                            anchors.topMargin: 20
                            styleColor: "#ffffff"
                            font.pointSize: 12
                            font.family: "Verdana"
                            renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                        }
                    }

                    model: {dtc_reading_connection.dtc_list_model} //I don't know how to define here different models depending on ECU name from parent ListView model data

                    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
                }
            }

            model: {dtc_reading_connection.ecu_list_model} //parent ListView model with ECU names

            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
        }
    }
```

I've tried to set up a new str function argument with ECU name inside, but it doesn't work, I cannot pass this str from QML so there's a lack of argument error:

```
@pyqtProperty(list, notify=dtc_list_emmition_signal)
def dtc_list_model(self, ecu):
    if ecu == 'uBCM':
        return self.dtc_list_uBCM
    else:
        return self.dtc_list_ACU
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring dtc_list_model as a pyqtSlot instead of a pyqtProperty? Then you would call it from qml and pass in the parameter you need.

Comment: @JarMan, in this case QML will stop to identify this model as model and QML line with model declaration will return "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using a single `ListView` and its section property?

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html#section-prop

Here's an example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "black" }
    title: "ListView sections"
    Frame {
        width: parent.width
        background: Rectangle {
            border.color: "yellow"
            color: "#555"
        }
        ListView {
            width: parent.width
            height: contentHeight
            implicitWidth: width
            implicitHeight: height
            anchors.margins: 20
            model: listModel
            delegate: ListViewDelegate { }
            section.property: "sec"
            section.delegate: ListViewSectionDelegate { }
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        ListElement { sec: "uBCM"; part: "p1230" }
        ListElement { sec: "uBCM"; part: "u1100" }
        ListElement { sec: "uBCM"; part: "f1441" }
        ListElement { sec: "ACU"; part: "a1111" }
        ListElement { sec: "ACU"; part: "b2222" }
        ListElement { sec: "ACU"; part: "c3333" }
        ListElement { sec: "ESCL"; part: "a1330" }
        ListElement { sec: "ESCL"; part: "u0008" }
        ListElement { sec: "ESCL"; part: "p1856" }
    }
}

// ListViewSectionDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Label {
    width: ListView.view.width
    text: section
    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    color: "white"
    background: Item { }
    padding: 4
}

// ListViewDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Label {
    width: ListView.view.width
    text: part
    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    background: Rectangle {
        color: "yellow"
        border.color: "#555"
        border.width: 3
    }
    padding: 4
    color: "black"
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)